# Getting different results from same request with MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am writing an app using microsoft graph api. I want to run the command.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives
```

Unfortunately when I do this with the app I get different results from the app and graph explorer.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

```
{
    "access-control-allow-origin": "https://graphtryit.azurewebsites.net",
    "access-control-expose-headers": "Content-Encoding,Server,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Expose-Headers,Strict-Transport-Security,request-id,client-request-id,x-ms-ags-diagnostic,x-ms-resource-unit,OData-Version,X-FE-DATA",
    "cache-control": "public, must-revalidate, max-age=300",
    "client-request-id": "$$ID OMITED$$",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false; charset=utf-8",
    "odata-version": "4.0",
    "request-id": "$$ID OMITED$$",
    "server": "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
    "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": "$$OMITED$$"
}
```

This is the header info for the App

```
    {
 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Content-Type':'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8',
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000',
 'request-id': '$$ID OMITED$$',
 'client-request-id': '$$ID OMITED$$',
 'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"$$OMITED DIFFERENT SERVER$$"}}',
 'OData-Version': '4.0',
 'Date': 'Tue, 01 Nov 2022 17:52:48 GMT'
    }
```

**Why do you think the two would yield different results?** The app has its permissions in place. It's an azure active directory app. The azure request yields one drive. While the graph explorer tool yields all the drives available. Lol new discovery some instances of the graph explorer show what the api does and the other doesn't

**New development:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#code-try-1
Shows all drives when you input /drives
but https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=drives&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com doesn't show all when you enter /drives

```
{
    "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "client-request-id": "$$ID OMITTED$$",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8",
    "request-id": "$$ID OMITTED$$"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out. The learn site outputs all fake data from

```
"access-control-allow-origin": "https://graphtryit.azurewebsites.net"
```

The learn site should not be used to compare to your applications output when debugging your application. Except to get a general idea of what normal output looks like.